# Get Google Calender Event Color (via PHP)

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to get the color of an event from my Google Calender. Title, desc and date works already. But I don't get it with the color.

I use the Code by Sarah Bailey.

```
$newmonth = $eventdate->format("M");
     $newday = $eventdate->format("j");
     $newtime = $eventdate->format("H:i");
     $description = $event->description;

    ?>

<div class="entry">
    <div class="color" style="background-color: #_HERE COLOR OF EVENT_;">
        ---
    </div>
```

Can you please help me to get the ColorId from an event?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [colors get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get)?

```
$colors = $service->colors->get();

// Print available calendarListEntry colors.
foreach ($colors->getCalendar() as $key => $color) {
  print "colorId : {$key}\n";
  print "  Background: {$color->getBackground()}\n";
  print "  Foreground: {$color->getForeground()}\n";
}
// Print available event colors.
foreach ($colors->getEvent() as $key => $color) {
  print "colorId : {$key}\n";
  print "  Background: {$color->getBackground()}\n";
  print "  Foreground: {$color->getForeground()}\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it just gives me a white page (error). I placed the colors get into the script above.